# Notion API - Issue with creating pages

Tags: javascript, notion-api

After scouring the Notion docs, I can't figure out why I keep getting a 400 status back. My code:

```js
const { Client } = require("@notionhq/client");

const notion = new Client({
  auth: process.env.NOTION_TOKEN,
});

async function main() {
  try {
    await notion.pages.create({
      parent: {
        type: "database_id",
        database_id: process.env.DB_ID,
      },
      properties: {
        Name: [
          {
            text: {
              content: "Test name",
            },
          },
        ],
        Link: {
          url: "www.google.com",
        },
        Notes: [
          {
            text: {
              content: "sample notes",
            },
          },
        ],
        Year: [
          {
            text: {
              content: "2020",
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

main();
```

The API has no problem with the text fields. It's on the url column of key Link that I get the following error:

```
body.properties.Link.id should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.properties.Link.name should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
body.properties.Link.start should be defined, instead was `undefined`.
```

Further, it seems I get this same error as long as I'm not using a text column. I've gotten this error for relations and checkboxes as well. [Here](https://developers.notion.com/reference/page-property-values) are the docs I've been referring to for accessing page properties.

I also get this same error if I use the template from [this](https://developers.notion.com/reference/post-page) example for creating page titles:

```js
        Name: {
          title: [
            {
              text: {
                content: "Tuscan Kale",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
```

I checked and double checked my environment variables and integration permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the api returns a misleading error in this case, the issue is actually with the way you are specifying the title and rich_text properties.

```js
const { Client } = require('@notionhq/client');

const notion = new Client({
    auth: process.env.NOTION_TOKEN,
});

async function main() {
    try {
        await notion.pages.create({
            parent: {
                type: 'database_id',
                database_id: process.env.DB_ID,
            },
            properties: {
                Name: {
                    title: [
                        {
                            text: {
                                content: 'Test name',
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
                Link: {
                    url: 'www.google.com',
                },
                Notes: {
                    rich_text: [
                        {
                            text: {
                                content: 'sample notes',
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
                Year: {
                    rich_text: [
                        {
                            text: {
                                content: '2020',
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
            },
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

main();
```